# How to define the stream Result annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, struts2, struts2-codebehind-plugin

I need to export the Excel sheet, so calling action class method through Ajax call from dialog window. I have Excel icon, when I click the icon calling method and processing the backend data, and finally going to execute the below code and return the result to download the Excel sheet.

**jQuery Ajax calling:**

```
function callajax() {
     jQuery.ajax({
     url : '<s:url action="part" method="export"/>',
```

**Result method:**

```
@Result(name="success",type=StreamResult.class,value="",params={"inputName","inputStream"})
```

**Java code:**

```
    public String method {
    -----------------
    method to call backend...
    --------------------------
    httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    String filename = filters.getPeriod() + "_" +filters.getRegion() ;
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-disposition",
    "attachment; filename="+filename+".xls");
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
    builder.build(method1, method2, outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    return SUCCESS; }

In the build method has creating workbook

    WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
    workbookSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
    WritableWorkbook workbook =
    Workbook.createWorkbook(outputStream, workbookSettings);
```

and setting the all the values in sheet. Please advise.

**Trying as your advise :**

I'm using code behind , so result type on class name :

```
@Result(name="success",type=StreamResult.class,value="",params = {"contentType","application/octet-stream","inputName","inputStream","bufferSize","1024","contentDisposition","attachment;filename=\"${filename}\""})


public String method {
    -----------------
    method to call backend...
    --------------------------
String filename =   filters.getRegion() + "_" +
                filters.getCurrency();
File file = new File(filename);
inputStream = new FileInputStream(file); //getting error "java.io.FileNotFoundException:file "
builder.buildXL(OBJ1, OBJ2, file);
return SUCCESS;
}

buildxl(obj1,obj2,File file)
{
WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
    workbookSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
    WritableWorkbook workbook =
    Workbook.createWorkbook(file, workbookSettings);

-----
------
workbook.write(); 
workbook.close();
}
```

**Params values :**

```
params = 
{"contentType","application/octet-stream",
"inputName","inputStream",
"bufferSize","1024",
"contentDisposition","attachment;filename=\"${filename}\""})
```

**Log :**

```
2013-07-18 10:25:33,453 ERROR         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult - Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
2013-07-18 10:25:33,453 ERROR       org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation - Exception processing the result.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult.doExecute(StreamResult.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.executeResult(RestActionInvocation.java:241)
    at org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.processResult(RestActionInvocation.java:198)
    at org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.invoke(RestActionInvocation.java:146)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.execute(DefaultActionProxy.java:147)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1513)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
2013-07-18 10:25:33,499 DEBUG       org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation - No result returned for action at null
```

**`ClasspathPackageProvider`:**

```
org.apache.struts2.config.ClasspathPackageProvider - Adding parmeter[contentType:application/octet-stream] to result.
org.apache.struts2.config.ClasspathPackageProvider - Adding parmeter[inputName:inputStream] to result.
org.apache.struts2.config.ClasspathPackageProvider - Adding parmeter[bufferSize:1024] to result.
org.apache.struts2.config.ClasspathPackageProvider - Adding parmeter[contentDisposition:attachment;filename="${filename}"] to result.
```

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific. It's also not clear what you're trying to do in that method. And, Codebehind is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Return result as a binary stream

```
private InputStream inputStream;
private String filename; 

//getters here
public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
}

public String getFilename() {
  return filename;
}

@Result(name="success", type=StreamResult.class, value="inputStream", params={"contentType","application/octet-stream", "contentDisposition", "attachment;filename=\"${filename}\"", "inputName", "inputStream"})

String filename = filters.getPeriod() + "_" +filters.getRegion() ;
File file = new File(filename);
inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
return SUCCESS;
```

Comment: +${filename}+ "\"", - syntax error.$ is work here ? and i have to remove the all the headers and putting into params.

Comment: Please look into question section , i have updated.Because i'm sending outputstream to build method to create excel sheet all the properties.As we output stream servle response setting from setcontext type.Is there any way to keep these setting in code itself ? Otherwise core flow need to change.

Comment: You don't have to set content type (it's set by the result), and other code you should replace with the code from this answer.

Comment: which one(file or inputstream) i suppose to pass to workbook ? Workbook.createWorkbook(outputStream, workbookSettings);

Comment: If the method takes an `OutputStream` then you pass the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: sorry I got confused...File file = new File(filename);
inputStream = new FileInputStream(file); and Workbook.createWorkbook(file, workbookSettings);

Comment: You should create file first, then take an input stream of it, don't forget to call `write` and `close` on workbook returned by the `createWorkbook`.

Comment: inputStream = new FileInputStream(file); - getting an error java.io.FileNotFoundException:...as updated in question section for reference.

Comment: I meant a file is created after build.

Comment: builder method is working good , when return result type, its throwing error as "Error :org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult - Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.". Can you please advise.

Comment: The parameter `inputName` is specified in the `@Result` annotation. And this annotation has `params` property that should set parameters to the result. May be it doesn't support dynamic parameters, try to replace `${filename}` with the actual value, and don't forget that annotations are set on the class, not method in codebehind plugin. Why not to just switch to convention plugin and rid yourself of past mistakes?

Comment: inputName : inputStream values not taking here . params = {"contentType","application/octet-stream","inputName","inputStream","bufferSize","1024","contentDisposition","attachment;filename=\"${filename}\""}

Comment: Parameters aren't set to the result config, it would be messiah, enable debug for `ClasspathPackageProvider` and post the output.

Comment: Please advise how to enable debug ClasspathPackageProvider ?

Comment: Set the log level to debug, if you are using log4j then put `log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2.config=DEBUG`

Comment: Have updated the classpathpackageprovider in question section.

Comment: Didn't you see that `inputName` parameter value should be printed in the error message but you say it was [], either you have a method in the action `getInputName` or you have such parameters in the value stack, you should check that both.

Comment: What do you want to suppose, I don't like to suppose or guess something, I need the full action code to make decision about late apologizes. And it couldn't be solved until you debug the `StreamResult` and tell me why the value for the `inputName` is empty. You can remove the parameters `inputName`, `bufferSize` with their values from the `@Result` as they have the same default values as used in my code.

Comment: Because in your code value="" , but value must be inputStream, so that java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [stream] in the invocation stack.

Comment: Hmm... Where in my code did you see it? The value `stream` I didn't use in this answer (used `inputStream`, and as I said it could be removed because this value is used by default), may be you got it from another one?

Comment: Ouch, the `value` attribute, did you see if it affect the setting of parameters to the result? It would be strange if it's related only to the one parameter. And also keep in mind that parameters are set to the map by key-value pairs encountered by the `params` attribute.

Comment: yes , which i mention in above comment that value attribute only. params key/value are good, but if set the value attribute , then name[stream] getting the value.@Result(name="success",type=StreamResult.class,value="stream",params = {"contentType","application/octet-stream","inputName","inputStream","contentDisposition","attachment;filename=\"${filename}\""})

Comment: After set the value attribute i got error as "Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [stream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action."

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work, is the result executed? If it did then it worked.

Comment: Yes, the `value` overrides the `inputName` of stream result in codebehind plugin.

Comment: This also good idea :), but now Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack.I have getter method for inputStream, then why getting this error.

Comment: Any other Possibilities ?

Comment: What other possibilities do you want?