# Java Struts2 - Access .pdf file in WEB-INF folder in a JSP

Tags: java, struts2

I have a complicated issue.

I save a pdf file under `WEB-INF/folder/test.pdf`
But now, I want to be able to download that pdf file in a JSP file. I know that files in WEB-INF are not visible by URL, but I have tried all the answers possible in this page and none work.

```
String pathDownload = ((ServletContext) ActionContext.getContext().get(StrutsStatics.SERVLET_CONTEXT)).getRealPath("/WEB-INF/folder/")+ "\\";
```

And in my JSP file I got:

```
<a href="<%=pathDownload%>/test.pdf" >
```

So, URL route is correct, but it does nothing when clicking, returning null.

I tried to write something in the file `web.xml`, but nothing works.

Also tried `InputStream` in the `execute()` in that class who **extends `ActionSupport` implements `SessionAware`**

Can anyone help with an explanation what must I do?

Comment: You *know that files in WEB-INF are not visible by URL*, so you need to open this file in action and stream it to client.

Answer (score 2):

It's not relevant that the client side "knows" about actual path on the server side. So, it won't help if you "tell" the client side about the actual path.
Instead of:
`<a href="<%=pathDownload%>/test.pdf" >`, just do `<a href="download.action?file=folder/test.pdf" >`.
To make this example to work, you have to map the `download` url action with an action that have a stream result type:

```
<action name="download">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
        <param name="inputName">fileStream</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="document.pdf"</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

In your `DownloadAction.java`, you have just to read the file mentioned by the `file` parameter and create a property called `fileStream` with the file content:

```
public class DownloadAction extends ActionSupport{

    private InputStream fileStream;
    private String file;

    public InputStream getFileStream() {
        return fileStream;
    }

    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
            new File(
                ((ServletContext) ActionContext.getContext().get(StrutsStatics.SERVLET_CONTEXT))
                .getRealPath("/WEB-INF/folder/")
                +
                file
            )
        );
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly!!! It worked!! I didn't know I needed another mapping java for it, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the path of the file to the action method of your action class like this

```jsp
<s:a href="download.action?file=%{pathDownload}/test.pdf">Download</s:a>
```

Property `file` of type `String` will be used populate the parameter value.

Then use to initialize a `inputStream` property as `getResourceAsStream()` and return `stream` type result providing a getter for the `inputStream` property.

If you are using convention configuration you can find similar implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674273/573032).

Comment: Great! Please, accept the answer, if you don't know how to do it read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).